# update model with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm obtaining with a post method the value of a parameter

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"88f1KdoixHkPXIQJs4Vmg0kj9Sxrc+eM0DGSbD0B1xs=", "adverts"=>{"title"=>"fdasfa", "features"=>"", "description"=>"", "areadescription"=>"", "rooms"=>"", "bathroom"=>"", "price"=>"", "type"=>"", "source"=>"", "originaldate"=>""}, "commit"=>"Save Adverts"}
```

And obtaining the specific value:

```
@advert = params[:adverts]
```

advert has exactly the same names of the fields of the table named advertTable.
How I can parse the advert variable to the same time of my model advertTable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should take a loot at the tutorial. 
In order to pass the variable to an object, you have to tell what object this is... And then pass the parameters TO the object. So,

```
@advert=Advert.new(params[:adverts])
@advert.save
```

However, this is not good practice... For updating and creating you should use strong parameters. This way, a bad guy will not update, let's say, the id column or other columns that are not public.

The best way to do it:

```
@advert=Advert.new(advert_params)
@advert.save
```

And in the update action:

```
@advert=Advert.find(params[:id]) #this comes from the url
@advert.update(advert_params)
```

And lower, in your same controller, under "private" section:

```
private
def advert_params
    params.require(:adverts).permit(:title, :features, :description, :areadescription, :rooms, :bathroom, :price, :type, :source, :originaldate)
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I needed add the `private def advert_params` now works!